# pandas dataframe substring df['column1'].str[:'column2']

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, substring

I have a dataframe (df) with columns (A=object, B=int64)
what I need is to be able to get a substring of 'A' based on the value of 'B'.

I want to get 'C' like this:

```
  A      B    C
=====  =====  =========================
Jimmy  4      Jimm
Tommy  2      To
Karl   3      Kar
Jane   1      J
=====  =====  =========================
```

So far I tried this:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].str[:df['B']]
```

I also tried this:

```
l = (lambda x,y: str(x)[:y])

df[['A','B']].apply(l)
```

no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The following works but it won't be fast as it's operating as a loop over every row, the key thing here is to pass param `axis=1` to operate row-wise and we can than access each column's value:

```
In [46]:

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'][:x['B']], axis=1)
df
Out[46]:
       A  B     C
0  Jimmy  4  Jimm
1  Tommy  2    To
2   Karl  3   Kar
3   Jane  1     J
```

So just to look at your attempts and why they don't work: `df['C'] = df['A'].str[:df['B']]` this will fail as you are trying to subscript every element in column A by passing a series, it has to be some constant int value unfortunately, it's a nice idea but won't work.

```
l = (lambda x,y: str(x)[:y])
df[['A','B']].apply(l)
```

This won't work because the result of `df[['A', 'B']]` is a just your original df, you've not specified the `axis` to operate on so the default is `0` which is column wise, in effect your lambda now fails as only a single param is passed which on the first iteration will be `df['A']`, so the only way to make this work is to operate row-wise by passing param `axis=1`. I can't currently think of a better way here at the moment.

Comment: EdChum, txs v-much. it works. the axis=1 trick made it work. txs for the explanation also.